# How to properly handle indefinite generators in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Let's say we have a generator that is indefinite, where new elements can arrive at any moment with significant (up to indefinite) delay.

An example of such generator is `tail -F` command. In python (omitting various edge cases) it could be implemented as the following:

```
def tail_follow(file):
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if line:
            yield line
        else:
            sleep(1.0)
```

Obvious problem with this generator is that it may cause caller's thread to sleep forever. Therefore it should provide caller's side a way to break iteration.

The solution I came up is the following:

```
def tail_follow(file, on_delay_callback):
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if line:
            yield line
        else:
            if on_delay_callback():
                break
            else:
                sleep(1.0)
```

Is this the only way to get this behavior with Python? I know that there is a send function that allows 2-way data transfer, can it be used to make solution more pythonic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the problem with your approach. I think you are almost there. If you change your generator to `yield None` when there is nothing to return, then you can simply test for that.

See the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import time

tailpath = "./tailfile"
fd = open(tailpath)

def tail_follow(file):
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if line:
            yield line
        else:
            yield None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in tail_follow(fd):
        if line:
            print ("found: %s" % (line))
        else:
            # do something useful
            time.sleep(1.0)
```

Or alternatively:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mytail = tail_follow(fd)
    while True:
        # do something useful
        time.sleep(1.0)
        # anything to tail ?
        line = next(mytail)
        if line:
            print ("found: %s" % (line))
```

[Jeff Knupp](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) has a nice post about infinite generators.

Comment: I guess `if line:` should be `if line is None:` in `__main__`.

Comment: Can you think of any example in standard library (maybe asyncio?) that does it?

Comment: In both examples the `if line:` is correct because you want to do something with the result if `tail_follow` yields something and ignore it when it yields `None`. You can easily see that it works if you execute `touch ./tailfile` to create the file to tail and then `echo abc>>./tailfile` to add characters to it. In a second shell you then call the script and every time you echo something in the first shell to `.tailfile`, it is printed in the second shell. I'm not familiar with `asyncio`.

Comment: I meant `if line is not None`, sorry. `if line` will fail if line is empty which isn't desired behavior.

Comment: Both `if line:` and `if line is not None:` behave the same here (1). If the file your tailing contains an empty line, there is still data: `line` will contain `\n` and the examples will print an empty line. If you don't want empty lines, then your application can check for them and ignore them. This leaves the generator generic i.e. contains no behaviour or design decisions. (1) There are cases in which the behaviour is different e.g. if the variable would be a number.

Comment: Ok I agree, in this particular example that relies on behavior of readline it makes sense. But since this example is all about generator returning either value or `None`, I'd put extra emphasis on that fact by explicitly checking whether value is None. Will require rework though. Other than that excellent example, already re-worked my generators :)